# McLaurin series and $n$-th derivative of a function at the origin

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

The aim is to find the nth derivative of the given function using a known series from $e^x$.
$$ e^x = \sum_{n \to 0}^ \infty { \frac {x^n} {n!} } $$
and now to find

$$ f(x) = -x^5 {e^{x^3-1}}$$
$$ f(x) = -x^5 \frac {e^{x^3}} {e} $$
and so after using the known series to find this series above we get...
$${ \frac {1}{e}} \sum_{n \to 0}^{ \infty } (-1)^n \frac {x^{3n+5}}{n!}$$

and we have to find the $f^{(100)}(0)$ I did it like $ 3n + 5 = 100 \to 3n = 95 \to n = \frac {95}{3} \notin \Bbb N$
and also find $f^{(101)}(0)$ = 32 (similar method as above), and for 32 we get $$(-n)^{32}. \frac {101!} {32!}$$

Could anyone please spot my mistake and show me the proper method to do so?  I'm kinda new to infinite series.

Comment: Why the $(-1)^n$ ?

Answer (score 5):

Since $e^x=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ we have $e^{x^3}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{3n}}{n!}$ and $-x^5 e^{x^3-1} = -\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{3n+5}}{n! e}$.
$100$ is not a number of the form $3n+5$, hence $f^{(100)}(0)$ equals zero.
On the other hand $101=3\cdot 32+5$, hence
$$ f^{(101)}(0) = 101!\left(-\frac{1}{32! e}\right) = -\frac{101!}{32!e}.$$
Obviously $f^{(101)}(0)$ cannot depend on any "$n$".

Comment: Hey so was I correct in finding the function? and what about the $f^{101}(0) $ part?

Comment: @PrathikGurudatt: answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Note that when you plug $x^3$ for $x$ into $x^n$ you get $(x^3)^n=x^{3n},$ not $x^{3^n}.$

So in fact the non-zero coefficients in that series appear for exponents of the form $3n+5,$ in other words, for those integers which leave a remainder of 2 when divided by 3. As 100 is not one of those numbers, we have
$$
f^{(100)}(0) = 0.
$$

Comment: Mistake noted, and updated.